# Displaying svg elements in curve

Tags: javascript, html, math, svg

Currently I have placed elements in line so all elements of `y` will be 15 (constant) and x will be increasing constantly so elements will in line. Now I need to place elements in curve how to achieve it .

Please check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stadicshock/PByLZ/).

I need to display elements in curve something like this:

[image]

Comment: curve image -http://uploads.im/F04MI.png

Comment: So you need to vary the 'cy' as you cross the page.  What is the problem you are having with doing that?

Comment: ya i need to create dynamically so i need formula to find the value cy of each element..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with.  It is fairly basic trigonometry.

We start with some configuration/setup:

```
// The centre of the big curve the dots sit on
var  curveX = 300;
var  curveY = 800;
// The radius of the big curve
var  curveRadius = 400;

// The radius of the dots
var  dotRadius = 20;

var  numDotsPerRow = 10;
var  numRows = 5;
```

We have to step along the circumference of the "big curve".  So the first calculation is the angle between the dots.

```
// The step in big-curve angle between the dots
var  stepAngle = Math.asin(dotRadius / curveRadius) * 2;
```

We will centre each row of dots and use symmetry to draw two dots (left side and right side) each time through the loop.  So each row starts at half the step angle either side of centre.

```
// Centre dots on each row start half this angle on either side of centre
var  startAngle = stepAngle / 2;
```

There is a loop for each row of dots

```
var  svg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

for (var j=0; j<numRows; j++)
{
   var  currentAngle = stepAngle / 2;
```

And the inner loop for the dots on the row

```
   for (var i=0; i<(numDotsPerRow/2); i++)
   {
      // The centre of the dot relative to the curve centre
      var  dx = curveRadius * Math.sin(currentAngle);
      var  dy = curveRadius * Math.cos(currentAngle);

      // Add dots to each side/half of curve
      makeDot(mysvg, curveX-dx, curveY-dy, dotRadius);
      makeDot(mysvg, curveX+dx, curveY-dy, dotRadius);

      currentAngle += stepAngle;
   }
```

After each row is done, we step upwards by the diameter of a dot and draw another row.

```
   // Step the centre of the curve up by the diameter of a dot
   curveY -= dotRadius * 2;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/54Q2P/)